# What happens when delete a polymorphic object without a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, virtual, delete-operator, virtual-destructor

In following example, `b` is a polymorphic pointer type whose **static** type is `Base*` and whose **dynamic** type is `Derived*`.

```
struct Base 
{
  virtual void f();
};

struct Derived : Base 
{ 

};

int main()
{
   Base *b = new Derived();
   // ...
   delete b;
}
```

What happens when `b` is deleted without a virtual destructor?

Comment: read this as well https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/OOP52-CPP.+Do+not+delete+a+polymorphic+object+without+a+virtual+destructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtual destructor missing for base class in polymorphism = Ressource leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455750/virtual-destructor-missing-for-base-class-in-polymorphism-ressource-leak)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens when b is deleted without a virtual destructor?

We don't know. The behavior is undefined. For most actual cases the destructor of `Derived` might no be invoked, but nothing is guaranteed.

[5.3.5 Delete
[expr.delete]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3)

(emphasis mine)

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the
>   object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static
>   type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be
>   deleted and **the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the
>   behavior is undefined**.

Comment: @downvoter Please tell me where I'm wrong so I can improve it.