# Is it ok to inherit from std::string to provide type consistency?

Tags: c++

I want a class to store the name of a team. I could use std::string for this but it is not really semantically correct. An std::string means any string while my team name can't be either empty or longer than 10 characters.

```cpp
class TeamName {
public:
  TeamName(std::string _teamName) : teamName(std::move(_teamName))
  {
    if (teamName.length() == 0 || teamName.length() > 10) {
      throw std::invalid_argumet("TeamName " + teamName + " can't be empty or have more than 10 chars." );
    }
  }

private:
  std::string teamName;
};
```

I like this: I'm checking the integrity of the name only once, future developers that never heard of this requirement won't be able to propagate invalid names from their new functions, there is an obvious place in the program logic to place exception handlers, etc.

But this construction means I have to use getters and setters to interact with the name, which pollutes the code a lot. If I inherit from std::string, however, the code barely changes and I can treat TeamName exactly as an std::string

```cpp
class TeamName : public std::string {
public:
  TeamName(std::string _teamName) : std::string(_teamName)
  {
    if (length() == 0 || length() > 10) {
      throw std::invalid_argumet("TeamName " + teamName + " can't be empty or have more than 10 chars." );
    }
  }
};
```

Is this bad practice? It feels conceptually correct for me.

What's the way to achieve the consistency I want and still be able to use the wrapper no different from how I use a string?

Comment: The [`std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) destructor is not `virtual`, so inheriting from `std::string` will not work very well. If you want input validation then I suggest you do it at the time of input instead (and since invalid input is rarely exceptional, I'd recommend against using exceptions as well).

Comment: I would define a class with **private data attribute of type `std::string`**; your class can then implement operators which can verify your restrictions. By operator overloading you may reach the string-like behavior you ask for.

Comment: No need to inherit here. Wrap your `std::string` and modify the public interface of `TeamName` as you see fit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good insight, thanks! But even if I'm not going to overload anything is it still bad?

Comment: @nivpeled That means I have to overload a lot of operators, no way out?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `private` inheritance mostly sidesteps the `virtual` destructor problem. But that's very close to a `private`  member.

Comment: @FelipeCoimbra I think, **since you don't try to use polymorphism**, it should be fine to inherit `std::string`.

Comment: @FelipeCoimbra Depending on your use case, you can probably get away with just adding an `operator std::string&()` and/or `operator const char*()`.

Comment: Generally, if a class doesn't have a `virtual` destructor it's usually not meant for inheritance. Virtual destructors are needed if you ever want to use polymorphism and have a custom destructor in your own child-class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude lack of a virtual destructor is only a problem if you delete derived objects via a base class pointer.

Answer (score 5):

One potential problem with the inheritance is that it lets people treat your `TeamName` as a normal `std::string`. Example:

```
class TeamName : public std::string {
public:
    TeamName(std::string _teamName) : std::string(_teamName)
    {
        if (length() == 0 || length() > 10) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("TeamName " + *this + " can't be empty or have more than 10 chars.");
        }
    }
};

void appendToString(std::string& s)
{
    s.append(" this is a long text, and the resulting teamname is no longer valid...");
}

int main()
{
    TeamName t = std::string("CoolTeam");
    std::cout << "The teamname is: " << t << std::endl;

    appendToString(t);
    std::cout << "And now it is: " << t << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
The teamname is: CoolTeam
And now it is: CoolTeam this is a long text, and the resulting teamname is no longer valid...
```

<s>It is possible to protect your inherited `TeamName` from all illegal changes - just overload `.append` and all other functions that can do anything to invalidate it. But with inheritance the problem becomes finding all the functions that have to be checked/restricted, and then writing an overload that handles it.</s>

EDIT: Not true, as pointed out in the comments, member functions in `std::string` are not marked as `virtual`. This means that if you access a `TeamName` through a pointer or ref to `std::string` then you *will* get the `std::string` implementation, and no amount of overloading will be able to protect your `TeamName` from modifications.

On the other hand, with a private string people can only touch your data through the functions you let them access.

Comment: There's also a problem that a `TeamName` can be passed to any function that accepts a `std::string &` and that function can all any of `std::string`s member functions even if `TeamName` has re-implemented all of them.   After all, that function has no reason to assume the `std::string` passed to it is actually something else.

Comment: Yes, reimplement methods would not help since `std::basic_string` is not polymorphic. They need to be marked as `virtual` in the base class too, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Fareanor That is a good point that I did not consider. I have revised my answer to remove the faulty "you can make it work if you really want" paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

In C++17, you could use `std::string_view` as target type of an implicit conversion instead:

```
class TeamName {
  std::string val;
public:
  TeamName(std::string name): val(std::move(name)) { /* snip */ }

  operator std::string_view() const {
    return val;
  }
};
```

This lets you use `TeamName` everywhere you could use a `std::string_view`, while disallowing modification (so your invariant on the length holds after object creation). Of course, that requires the parts of your code that should consume the object to know about `std::string_view`.

If `std::string_view` is not feasible for you, you could define the conversion to `const std::string&` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it depends on how your derived class `TeamName` is supposed to be used.

All you have to know is that, `std::basic_string` does not have a `virtual` destructor (**edit:** and is not polymorphic by the way).

---

So, the possible issues would appear if you ever try to use polymorphism (i.e. access a `TeamName` object through a `std::string` object).

Indeed (example), the following:

```
std::string * ms = new TestName; // Polymorphism
delete ms;                       // Undefined behaviour
```

Here, when you call `delete`, only the destructor of `std::string` will be called.

The issue is that since the destructor of `TestName` will never be called in such a case, you open the door to memory leaks.
Moreover deleting the derived object though pointer to base (which does not have a `virtual` destructor) is **Undefined Behaviour**. You may be interested to take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39632632/11455384).

This is why, in order to avoid issues, **one rule of thumb is to never inherit from a base class that does not have a destructor marked as `virtual`**.

---

But, if you don't intend to use polymorphism at all, it should be fine to make `TestName` inherit from `std::string`.

**Edit:** But I would not recommend you to do so, because you can't prevent anyone that would use your code in the future to misuse your class (e.g. giving it to a function that expects a `std::string&` for example, as it is polymorphism too).

---

**EDIT:** <sub>(details about why we can't use polymorphism)</sub>

Of course, the lack of a `virtual` destructor is not all of the story. We cannot use polymorphism because **`std::string` is not polymorphic**.

Indeed, in order to use polymorphism, the base class needs to be polymorphic.
In other words, the base class needs at least one `virtual` member function (which can be the destructor of course).

If this requirement is not filled, no vtable (virtual table) will be emitted for this structure.
Consequently, if we try to use polymorphism anyway, whether it is through pointer or through reference, the real object type and implementation will never be found if we try to access it through a non-polymorphic base (**dynamic type resolution is impossible without a vtable**).
Moreover, an other consequence is that we will become subject to **object slicing** too (everything about the derived object members will be lost/sliced away).

Comment: You can use polymorphism, it's just the deletion that can't be performed through a base pointer. Any other code that uses `std::string&` or `std::string*` will work fine.

Comment: @patatahooligan This is literally what I wrote, _"deleting the derived object though pointer to base (which does not have a virtual destructor)"_. Moreover, I'm afraid you're wrong, you can't use polymorphism with a non-polymorphic class. A class needs at least one `virtual` member function in order to be polymorphic (and so, have a vtable).

Comment: I'm referring to your last line that is misleadingly implying the lack of virtual destructor doesn't allow "polymorphism at all".

Comment: @patatahooligan Yes and I confirm. Since `std::basic_string` is not polymorphic, you are subject to object slicing if you try it anyway. Moreover, all the derived methods, including the reimplemented ones will be **unknown** if you tries to access them through a non-polymorphic base.

Comment: Well, "the lack of any `virtual` member function" I mean, because we need a vtable in order to use polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is not meant to be inherited from publicly. You can inherit privately, but private inheritance is more or less the same as composition and has no big advantage over it.

That being said, it is not the worst practice (even public inheritance can be ok when used with caution), but I think you are overcomplicating the matters. One main job of a class is to ensure that its invariants hold at any time. If you have a `Team` that has a name as member and that name has certain invariants (not longer than 10 characters, no empty string), it is also completely fine to have a `std::string` member and let the `Team` take care of those constraints.

Sometimes you only need to check constraints once. Suppose a `Team` gets a name when constructed and after that the name cannot change. In such situation, the following is a pattern I use sometimes:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
struct TeamName {
    std::string value;
    TeamName(std::string value) : value(value) {
        if (value.length() == 0 || value.length() > 10) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("TeamName " + value + " can't be empty or have more than 10 chars." );
        }
    }
    operator std::string() { return value; }
};

struct Team {        
    Team(TeamName name) : name(name) {}
    private:
    std::string name; 
};

int main() 
{
    try {
        Team x{std::string("")};
    } catch (std::exception& e) { std::cout << e.what(); }

}
```

Neither the user of the `Team` nor the `Team` itself has to bother with validating the name. Also both work with a plain string. The `TeamName` is merely used for validation.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm checking the integrity of the name only once, future developers that never heard of this requirement won't be able to propagate invalid names from their new functions, there is an obvious place in the program logic to place exception handlers, etc.

It then is a bad idea to inherit the class with `public` because this will expose all string manipulation functions, and you would need to make sure that none of them would break your constraints, like:

```
TeamName test;
test.append( … ); // could make the name longer then 10
test.clear(); // name is 0
```

You could overwrite each of those current functions and add a check for constraints, but what if you forgot one?

Or you inherit with visibility `protected` and only expose the functions you need, but then it is just like a wrapper, so you didn't gain anything over an inheritance.

So I see more cons about inheriting from `string` in that case then benefits.